# Whether app connect to BLE device successfully or not run on jailbreak device?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

App run in the jailbreak device with core bluetooth framework,whether app connect to BLE device successfully or not? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CoreBluetooth Framework is not a private framework so you dont have to jailbrake  for it . `Using core bluetooth you can connect the BLE devices` . There are two modes :

1. Central
2. peripheral

In central mode device is scanning for the peripherals . The peripheral having the **services** and **characteristic** . The characteristics either **Read,Write or notify** .So after connecting the device you can actually write or read the data from the peripheral . You can check the [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html) application for your reference.

Comment: I know that corebluetooth framework is not a private framework. My app works fine run in the non-jailbreak device,but I don't know run in the jailbreak device what will happens?

Comment: My app have uploaded app store,link: https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/keep/id599508465?ls=1&mt=8

Comment: fine . It would be better if you provide this information in question .